# SQLException after an Array.exists?(object) with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this strange SQL error when I try to know wether an object is in an array:

```
@announcement = Announcement.first
puts "YAY" if current_user.announcements_read.include?(@announcement)
```

Error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT "announcements".id FROM "announcements"  INNER JOIN "readings" ON "announcements".id = "readings".announcement_id    WHERE ("announcements"."id" = 3) AND (("readings".user_id = 1))  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)

(the middle table between `users` and `announcements` is `readings`, and it works perfectly when I do something like `user.announcements_read.include?(announcement)` in the console)

But **it works** when I do the opposite request:

```
puts "YAY" if @announcement.read_by.include?(current_user)
```

What is going on here?
Why does the first request work in the console but not in the app?
Why do `current_user.announcements_read.include?` gets an SQL error when `user.announcements_read` doesn't?

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `announcements_read` is a named scope, with an `:order` clause which looks something like `:order => "created_at"`. It's ambiguous because the `created_at` column is in more than one table in the query. Fixing it should be straightforward -- the order clause is a SQL fragment, so you should be able to prefix `created_at` with the appropriate table name.

As to why the other methods don't generate an error, perhaps you have different environments? Can you look at the logs to see what queries are being generated?